# DialogFlow : how to ask user to spell a word and can we increase the number of "error" before being disconnected?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I've got two basic other questions about DialogFlow and integration with google home / assistant, I didn't find it on my previous researches, but maybe miss it somewhere -really hope not as I do not want to put burden, but one user in google circle insisted me to consider to use stackoverflow for further questions-:

- Can we ask to the user to Spell to Dialogflow some specific words orally? ex: spelling an email to avoid error / password spelling too
- can we increase the number of "errors" when  the assistant is collecting wrong answers from the user? (after two wrong attemps it disconnect from the app, I would like to increase this)

Thanks a lot !
and really I hope that my question is not at the wrong place, as the rules seem very stringent per my understanting,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these features are available in Dialogflow directly, but it is possible to build upon these into your application specifically.

**Spell words orally**

Trying to spell something is probably not a good user experience, and it may be more useful to [Multi-surface conversations](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) so that the user can input this through a smartphone.

However, if you do want to do this, you can have an intent in your webhook which will listen for the user's raw text (`app.getRawInput()`) and remove all spaces and make smart substitutions ("at" => "@"). I can say letters individually in my email address. It ends up putting a few spaces in there, but in a way that does work more or less.

**More Fallback Prompts**

If you need to add more leniency for errors, you can track it yourself by replacing the default fallback intent with your own (accepting `@sys.any`) and providing your own re-prompts.

Keep in mind if the user is getting this error multiple times, then you should probably provide helpful suggestions that get the user back on the right flow. ("I'm sorry, I couldn't understand. Do you want to do X or Y?") After a few iterations of this, it may be better to end the conversation.

Comment: Very Clear, Thank you Nick for your explanations.